# addTarget function not firing after addGestureRecognizer function fires

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
\\Action 1
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
textfield.tag = self.numarr

\\Action 2
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
textfield.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Both functions fire but individually. When together the gesture function fires but the 2nd (addTarget) doesn't fire. Any fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap gesture is not suitable for `UITextField` you may use `textDidBeginEditing`.
Still if you want a tap effect you may need to use some transparent overlay using `UIImageView` or `UIButton`.
`UITextField` has delegate methods, you might want to consider implementing those. Or just add action event to your textfield.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textDidBeginEditing(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)
```

Then implement this:

```
func textDidBeginEditing(sender:UITextField) -> Void
{
   // handle begin editing event
}
```

Similarly you can place a transparent button and inside the action of that button you can place your desired code and also hide the button from the view till the control change from `UITextField`.

Comment: Works great! A UITapGestureRecognizer isn't required when this is around

Comment: Great! happy coding.